# Not able to use React-Native-Share in expo-app

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules, react-native-share

I made a project using Expo. I wanted to share multiple components at once. I tried using expo sharing but it does not support multiple sharing. I ejected my project, followed the steps in the installation guide of react-native-share library, but I am getting the following error. I cant seem to find the solution.
Can anyone help me?

```
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNShare' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:105:15 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:150:4 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:26:18 in handleError
at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:27:16 in createErrorHandler
at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:32:8 in <anonymous>
at node_modules/@react-native/js-polyfills/error-guard.js:51:16 in ErrorUtils.applyWithGuard
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:237:19 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.0.102:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in metroRequire
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:694:6 in runUpdatedModule
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:549:20 in metroHotUpdateModule
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:58:4 in define
at http://192.168.0.102:19000/Screens/HostGameScreens/PlayerTicketsScreen.bundle?platform=android&hot=false&strict=false&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:null in global
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js:21:4 in inject
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js:29:15 in HMRClient
- ... 11 more stack frames from framework internals
```